# ROS2 Libex directory error

Tags: ros, ros2, roslaunch, ros-humble

I get such an error:  [ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): package 'action_right' found at '/home/leyla/checkout/tutorialros2/colcon_ws/src/action_right/install/action_right', but libexec directory '/home/p/checkout/tutorialros2/colcon_ws/src/action_muxer/install/action_muxer/lib/action_muxer' does not exist.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide enough information to be able to reproduce your problem. There could be issues in your installation, environment setup, or compilation. So please explain how you are doing all three.